# getUserMedia is undefined on IOS 12.3

Tags: ios, cordova, getusermedia

I'm trying to do a barcode scanner application, I need to use getUserMedia to scan barcode and it works good. Now I am trying to make this application available on IOS but when I run it it show me this :

```
getUserMedia is not defined
```

I've tried to use webRTC-adapter but it doesn't change my situation, I looked on my phone's parameters but it never change my situation.

```
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<script>
    import adapter from 'webrtc-adapter'
    [...]
</script>
```

I need to have the camera's output inside my IOS app

Answer (score 1):

Is that in a WKWebView? getUserMedia is not supported there, star https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458 for updates.

Comment: It is supported now w/ the recent iOS update